# inherit hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet, error: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7

When trying to inherit `hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet` in openerp 7, an error appeared:

```
TypeError : Error when calling the metaclass bases
module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

After doing some research, some say that the inheritance is screwy, and `hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet` might be a module not a class. I need your help.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp.osv import fields, orm, osv
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from openerp import api
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import dateutil.parser
import datetime

class hr_timesheet_sheet(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet'

_columns = {
    'weekend': fields.integer( 'weekend'),
}
hr_timesheet_sheet()
```

I did import the right file of my custom module in  `__init__.py` file

```
import hr_timesheet_sheet
```

PS. I'm new with openerp and python

Comment: What is the model that you want to inherit?, hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet is not a model

Comment: in odoo v8 it did work for me, i<ve put the same code in openerp 7, I got the that error... and hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet is a class in hr_timesheet_sheet module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly how, but this worked for me:

```
class hr_timesheet_sheet():
_inherit = 'hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet'
_columns = {
   'weekend': fields.integer( 'weekend'),
}
hr_timesheet_sheet()
```

and you should go to **openerp**.py,  put this line:

```
'depends': [ 'hr','hr_timesheet_sheet'],
```

> you can keep your class as it is `class hr_timesheet_sheet(osv.osv):`